# SQL trigger update with nested aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested, aggregate

I have two tables `lt_wmi_men_org_cs` and `lt_wmi_men_venue_cs`.

What I want to do is to say in the venue table count how many rows exist (for that given season and type) and then multiply by the sessions field and update either directly into the org table (or a temp variable that will be used to update the org field).

This works.

```
declare @sum_wksp int = (select count(e.id_key) 
                         from LT_WMI_MEN_VENUE_CS e 
                         join lt_wmi_men_org_cs f on e.organization = f.customer_no
                         where e.season = f.season
                           and e.[type] = 1)
```

However, when I add the multiplication of the sessions that's where it doesn't work.

```
declare @sum_wksp int = (select (count(e.id_key)    * e.sessions) as 'val'
                         from LT_WMI_MEN_VENUE_CS e 
                         join lt_wmi_men_org_cs f on e.organization = f.customer_no
                         where e.season = f.season
                           and e.[type] = 1
                           and f.id_key = @id_key)
```

My data looks like this

`venue` table

```
season    type    sessions    organization
2016         1        4          46
2015         2        2          51
2011         1        3          21
2015         2        5          73
2016         1        2          46
```

`orgs` table

```
season    sum_type    customer_no
2016         NULL        46
2015         NULL        21
2011         NULL        73
2015         NULL        51
2016         NULL        29
```

So the bottom line is that `@sum_wksp` should if the season is `2016 (1 * 4) + (1 * 2)` and should equal = 6 in total.

This is a two part question - how would I fix the query to make it work?

Is there a more efficient way to update

Is there a way to update `lt_wmi_men_org_cs` directly without using a temporary variable?

To say

```
update lt_wmi_men_org_cs 
set wksp_sum = <query>
```

instead of

```
update lt_wmi_men_org_cs 
set wksp_sum = @sum_wksp
```

Comment: As posted your question has nowhere near enough information. Any responses at this point would be guessing at what you are trying to do. I suspect you just need to modify your update statement but it is not at all clear to me what that might be because I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I state in my question I need to run an update statement - and provide the example of a venue table followed by how I need to update my variable and what output I need. If i wasn't clear - I would like to have the update statement calculate all the sessions (based on a given type and season).  Such as if the season is 2016 and type is 1 I need it to count each line ( and multiply it by the amount of sessions and return that value).

Comment: It is very clear to you because you are familiar with the project and the data. I understand the basic gist of what you are trying to do. What I can't do is help provide any syntax because I don't know your table structures. You have to correlate your subquery to the outer table. Unless you can provide those details that is about all I can offer. I am offering to help but need details so I can.

Comment: @SeanLange I added table structure for the org table. There is a NULL field there it gets populated (by the update in the trigger) with the mathematical formula from the other table. the join (as i have it is on customer_no to organization and season- that part i got to work.  If type is 1 (or a specific value) count that row. (This is my first query).  Now what I would like is to count that row * how many sessions - for customer 46 and the 2016 season we should have 1 * 4 and 1 * 2 sessions.  Does that help?